# Selenium WebDriver Automation with NW.js and Chromium Extended Framework Desktop application implemented in web technologies

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to Automate my application which is a standalone desktop based application implemented with web technologies and  with chromium embedded framework that uses NW.js

The Application which iam testing, is a desktop based with web technologies implementation with NW.JS
The Application to be tested is actually embedded inside the Web Kit, which uses chromium and is a normal window and browser independent.
It does not make use of any of the traditional browsers(ie firefox,or IE or Safari, or Google chrome)
I wonder if selenium web driver can be used to test NW.JS sort of applications.
I will be grateful if anyone can help me

The selenium WebDriver Automated code is as follows

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;    
import java.util.Calendar;    
import java.util.Date;    
import java.util.Formatter;    
import java.util.Locale;    
import java.util.TimeZone;    
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;    
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class MyDummyTest

{

       public static void main(String args[])
       {    

            File chromium = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ChartInstaller Standalone\\nw.exe");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Program Files (x86)/ChartInstaller Standalone/chromedriver2_server.exe");      
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
            options.setBinary(chromium);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);                                    
       }
}
```

but when I execute this, I see a dialog box is displayed (as shown below).
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem?
I have installed already the NW.js package on windows 7 environment.

[image: Dialog box Cannot extract package, failed to unzip the package file]

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer : You need to use zip class of Selenium Web driver

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html and here is class detail page. Free to use your function that fit in your requirement. I think my example code should work too

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/io/Zip.java

Here is java Code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.io.Zip;

public class tempUnit {

    public void test() {

        Zip zip = new Zip();
        try {
        zip.unzip(new File("D:\\TmpFS"), new File("D:\\TmpFS.zip"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If following question answer is Yes than selenium should work.                                    1) You able to view source code ? 2) are you able to find xpath or css selector using FireBug ? 3) It is HTML objects ?

Comment: Thanks for responding,Let me be more clear,when i execute my piece of code, it opens a window application,in which i should be able to see my application which i want to test it. so it has nothing to do with the traditional browsers. first i should be able to launch my application in the window

Comment: Selenium is Web Automation browser and it works on HTML object. If you can't perform certain things that I asked above then selenium will not able to find HTML object.  It is opening your application because it is passing value to browser and browser open that URL after that it will not perform any action because it is not able to find HTML object.

Comment: The problem is that it does not open my application,instead it displays the error shown in the attached screeshot.so first of all i need to able to launch my application in the window(which is not browser)